# Part 2: When does the maximal root of this polynomial have unit magnitude? Prove an inverse linear relation between parameters

Tags: polynomials, stability

Examine the polynomial 
$$
x^{\tau+1}-\left(1+m\right)x^{\tau}+mx^{\tau-1}+\left(1-m\right)\alpha=0\,.
$$
with positive parameters $\tau,\alpha$ and $m<1$, and denote $\left|x_{\max}\left(\tau,\alpha,m\right)\right|$ as the
maximal magnitude of a root of this equation. For $\tau>1$, I observed numerically
that this root lies on the unit circle, i.e. 
$$
\left|x_{\max}\left(\tau,\alpha,m\right)\right|=1
$$
if and only if 
$$
\frac{1}{\alpha}= a(m)(\tau-1)+1
$$
for some positive function $a(m)$ which increases with $m$. This numerical relation could be seen here

[image]

I wonder if this linear relationship could be proved (at least in some limit), and perhaps even if one can find a simple form for $a(m)$.

Comment: a simpler special case of this question was asked and answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/331115/44790), but I couldn't extend the method used there to the general problem here (I get a more complicated expression which I do not know how to solve).

Thanks in advance!